# Handling exceptions in Socket programming

Tags: c#, exception

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String text = textBox1.Text;
        UdpClient udpc = new UdpClient(text,8899);
        IPEndPoint ep = null;

        while (true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Name: ");
            string name = "Connected";
            if (name == "") break;
            byte[] sdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(name);
            udpc.Send(sdata, sdata.Length);

            if (udpc.Receive(ref ep)==null)
            {
               MessageBox.Show("Host not found");               
            }
            else
            {                
                byte[] rdata = udpc.Receive(ref ep);
                string job = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rdata);
                MessageBox.Show(job);
            }               
        }
    }
```

I'm getting an error message  when my remote machine is not connected . with this code  im getting the errror.

```
if (udpc.Receive(ref ep)==null)
```

error  message is  **socket exception was unhanded** (  An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)

Comment: I'm assuming you want to know why this is happening and how you can prevent it? You need to make the question clearer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can wrap your infinite loop in a try catch block.

```
try
{
 while(true)
 {
   //your code
 } 
}
catch(Exception exception)
{
   //show exception.Message; 
}
finally{ //clean up}
```

Look at [how](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx) it is done.

Comment: I know this is old but catching all exceptions this way is likely to swallow up exceptions you are not truly handling. This will lead to silent failure and difficult to debug code. Always explicitly catch exceptions.

Comment: @bodangly While I agree mostly, I don't see how it will lead to silent failure. You can still tell or log which exception was thrown *and* rethrow the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the code in a

```
try
{

}
catch(SocketException se)
{

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

And start here for documentation on SocketException

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketexception.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If the exception is unhandled, so handle the exception:

```
    while (true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Name: ");
        string name = "Connected";
        if (name == "") break;
        byte[] sdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(name);

        try{
            udpc.Send(sdata, sdata.Length);
            byte[] rdata = udpc.Receive(ref ep);
            string job = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rdata);
            MessageBox.Show(job);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessaageBox.show(ex.toString());
        }
    }
```

The `try...catch` block is always recommended when the program accesses external resources (dbs, queues, file systems, http connections, udp sockets etc.)